# JSON works from URL not from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, json

Ok, first of all, thanks for reading my question, I'll try and add as much information as possible. I'm currently making a leaderboard for a Garrysmod Gametype, I got an API key from the coders of the Gamemode and with that API key I can extract JSON encoded arrays using a STEAM_ID

**Example:**
http://www.revoltgaming.com/api/?key=SENCORED_API_KEY&action=ajack_all&steamid=STEAM_0:0:5898349

If I use the code below everything works just fine:

```
$usr_url_everything = "http://www.revoltgaming.com/api/?key=114d788c3e40e91842f945f19c978e66&action=ajack_all&steamid=" . $_SESSION['STEAMID'];
$json_encoded = file_get_contents($usr_url_everything);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_encoded, true);
```

But what I do is, when a user joins for the first time, I extract his JSON string and save it in a MySQL database:

```
$usr_url_everything = "http://www.revoltgaming.com/api/?key=114d788c3e40e91842f945f19c978e66&action=ajack_all&steamid=" . $_SESSION['STEAMID'];
$json_encoded = file_get_contents($usr_url_everything);
$query = "INSERT INTO vm_leaderboard (`txtUser`, `txtJson`) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['STEAM64'] . "', '" . $json_encoded . "')";
```

But from the moment I try to **DECODE** the json string I pull from the database it just doesn't work, it return NULL. The json string I save in the database is identical as the string I get directly from the API page.

Here are the strings that get pulled from the database:
http://www.ishots-cave.com/revolt_/lb_applejack.php

Comment: Is the JSON string properly escaped for the database?

Comment: Just echo what you get from the database, and you'll probably see the answer to your question.

Comment: @Zagor23 The echo can be found here: http://www.ishots-cave.com/revolt_/lb_applejack.php (once for every row) and is identical to the one I pull from http://www.revoltgaming.com/api

Comment: @Waltzy `The string is saved as 'TEXT BLOB' in the database $leaderboard = new Database; $query = "SELECT * FROM vm_leaderboard"; $leaderboard->query($query); while ($leaderboard->nextRecord()) { // Decode his json string $json_encoded = $leaderboard->Record['txtJson']; echo $json_encoded; echo json_decode($json_encoded, true, 2);`

Comment: When inserting, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$json_encoded` and You should be fine...

Comment: @shadyyx I tried that now and still my json_decode does not want to decode. Is this because it has multiple layers? I'm really clueless here...

Comment: @shadyyx this is the return right now: `{"_Key":"72","_Name":"[Rv] Nissemand","_Clan":"","_SteamID":"STEAM_0:0:20320414","_UniqueID":"935863759","_Money":"5091","_Access":"e","_Arrested":"false","_Inventory":"handcuffs: 3; donator_pocket: 1; rv_van: 1; rope: 1; stimulants: 1; lobster: 44; gps: 1; small_pocket: 10","_Blacklist":"\u0003\u0001","_Misc":"{\"EquippedWeapons\":[],\"CarColor\":{\"nissan_skyline\":{\"b\":\"94.00\",\"g\":\"94.00\",\"r\":\"94.00\"}}}"}` **JSON LINT sees it as validated**

Comment: You should remove the API key from your example if that is the original one and not a public one.

Comment: @AndriesVerbanck - added my comment as an answer to be accepted. You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So As I posted in comment, converting it to an answer as it was helpful - the JSON string needs to be sanitized before inserting into the DB:

```
$usr_url_everything = "http://www.revoltgaming.com/api/?key=&action=ajack_all&steamid=" . $_SESSION['STEAMID'];
$json_encoded = file_get_contents($usr_url_everything);
// sanitize the JSON string
$json_encoded = mysql_real_escape_string($json_encoded);
// insert in common way
$query = "INSERT INTO vm_leaderboard (`txtUser`, `txtJson`) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['STEAM64'] . "', '" . $json_encoded . "')";
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I have tried your solution with TRUNCATE the table first so it could fully update and still it does not work

Comment: @AndriesVerbanck But in comment You replied that it seems to be validated :-) So where's the problem now?

Comment: Yes the json is validated, but the script still won't work. I've worked around this problem now by updating the database directly from the URL using a CHRON job that fires every 24 hours.

Comment: But the problem You asked about and I helped with is about JSON - that is repaired and valid now. Your next problem should be asked as new question.

Comment: You should accept an answer Andries, these people spent time helping you!

Comment: @Waltzy Sorry, forgot about it. Done now

Answer (score 1):

In the JSON file are backslashes and quotes which are probably changing your query.
So try again the code as following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO vm_leaderboard (`txtUser`, `txtJson`) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['STEAM64'] . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($json_encoded) . "')";
```

Comment: It still seems to fail. Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: Could you add to the line where you execute the query "or die(mysql_error());" and tell us the code? Or did you already and there isn't an error?

Comment: The SQL never had any errors in all attempts to make this code work. Thank you for your time